# QGIS installation failure -- post install fail and grass plugin errors

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

After installing QGIS through OSGEO4w, I receive a message about a post install fail. The report shows that many different .bat files failed to run. Here is just one example from the install report (from file directory /var/log/setup.log):

```
2020/08/11 18:37:25 running: cmd.exe /c "C:\OSGeo4W64\etc\postinstall\qgis-grass-plugin7.bat"
2020/08/11 18:37:26 abnormal exit: exit code=1
```

The base QGIS works fine, and I can view vector and raster data, and perform the QGIS included functions. However, I am unable to use grass, or any other plugins. I went through the process of manually uninstalling qgis (osgeo) and removing any folders and files. After re-installing, I still receive the same post install errors. I am installing QGIS version 3.14, but even installing the stable release (3.10) returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Removing RStudio path from qgis-g.env (find it from bin folder of QGIS installation) works for me. I found it from the following link
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38476